# svn command line: heredoc as message

Tags: svn, heredoc

Is there a way to use a heredoc as the message via the svn command?

I tried this:

```
$ echo <<TEXT | svn commit -m - 
  > line one input
  > line two input
  >TEXT
```

In my repository it just writes the dash as the message.

I tried searching around and didn't find a way of doing a multi-line input other than writing in the `\n` characters, but it would be great if I could just regular multi-lined text that I've already typed up as the input.

Is it possible using a different method or is it just wishful thinking?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an environment variable which will allow svn to open up your desired text editor to enter your commit message.

```
SVN_EDITOR
```

Look [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externaleditors.html) for more info

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use a here document you need to use the `-F` option.  But your other problem is you're using `echo` which doesn't take any input on stdin.  You want `cat`.

So the following will work:

```
cat <<TEXT | svn commit -F -
```

If you're doing this interactively I think you'll prefer [Jon Taylor's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1475461/jon-taylor) answer.